# Limpar label quando abro a página principal

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Estou a fazer um site em asp.net utilizando vb e quando faço refresh apago os dados das textbox's e queria tambem limpar o que está escrito na label 
conseguem me ajudar?

Estou a utilizar o codigo abaixo e nao esta a funcionar

```
 Label10.Text = ""
```

O código tem de ser em vb

Comment: Em que zona do código estás a colocar isso?

Comment: estou a colocar no load da página

Comment: Mostra o resto do teu código...

Comment: É pra dar certo José, observe se esse trecho de código esta no load da página mesmo, se não está dentro do IsPostBack e se antes de finalizar o Load ele não esta preenchendo a Label novamente.

Comment: era isso @WellingtonAraujo obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Então vô colocar minha descrição na resposta, para que q pergunta tenha uma resposta... ai você vota lá... rsrsrs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe se esse trecho de código esta no load da página mesmo, se não está dentro de um tratamento do IsPostBack(Ex: `If Not IsPostBack Then`) e se antes de finalizar o Load ele não esta preenchendo a Label novamente.